# How close automatically a PrimeFaces dialog after three seconds

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to show a dialog only three seconds and after close it automatically and  redirect an other faces page. How can I do it?

Thanks in Advance.

The dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Message" widgetVar="dlg1">  
<h:outputText value="your account is being blocked......" />  
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialog has two attributes `onShow` and `onHide`(you can reference in Primefaces doc), and you can use timeout to do it, you can try:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1" onShow="myFunction();" onHide="myStopFunction();"> </p:dialog>
<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction()
{
myVar=setTimeout(function(){ dlg1.hide()},3000);
}

function myStopFunction()
{
clearTimeout(myVar);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok thanks,and for redirect a other jsf page when the dialog close?

Comment: @user2683519 You can use javascript, ref: http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html

Comment: Instead of dlg1.hide(), use PF('dlg1').hide() for it to work in PrimeFaces 6